# Can I connect to default instance with computername\instanceid?

Tags: sql-server

I create default instance on SQL Server 2012 Standard.

When I set it up, I changed instance id from 'mssqlserver', which is a default value, to 'new_instance_id'.

For some reason I want to connect to the instance with computername\new_instance_id

Can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I believe since you have not opted for a default instance and named it, you have created a named instance: So you should be able to connect to this named instance.

Please refer to this MS article on how to connect the instance https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614(SQL.90).aspx

Also, just a add on:

Consider the following information when you decide whether to install a default or named instance of SQL Server:

> If you plan to install a single instance of SQL Server on a database
>   server, it should be a default instance. Use a named instance for
>   situations where you plan to have multiple instances on the same
>   computer. A server can host only one default instance. Any application
>   that installs SQL Server Express should install it as a named
>   instance. This will minimizes conflict when multiple applications are
>   installed on the same computer.